# Gazebo loading error turtlebot3

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I couldn't start turtlebot3 empty world simulation as,

```
ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo empty_world.launch.py here
```

I'm using Ros2 Foxy on Ubuntu 20.04 with Gazebo 11. But I can start webot turtlebot simulation below command:

```
ros2 launch webots_ros2_turtlebot robot_launch.py
```

[image: image description]

How can I fix the issues.

Thank you.[C:\fakepath\Screenshot from 2022-05-30 10-10-45.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/16538952695891573.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401595/gazebo-loading-error-turtlebot3/) by [girayuzun](https://answers.ros.org/users/24517/girayuzun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2022-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-05-30**:
Can you check if you can start `gzserver` alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your error seems to be the same as [another question](https://answers.ros.org/question/358847/cannot-launch-gzclient-on-a-launch-file-results-in-shared_ptr-assertion-error/). Can you try the solution provided there?

Run `. /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh` then start Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2022-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-05-30**:
I have those lines in my `~/.bashrc` for it:

```
stat /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh &> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    source /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh
fi
```

**Comment by [girayuzun](https://answers.ros.org/users/24517/girayuzun/) on 2022-05-30**:
both worked for me. Thank you.

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-30**:
If it's been solved, could you accept my answer as correct?